# What is the concept of God according to hindusim?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, upanishads

I a confused because Shiv puran say Shiva is the supreme God. Bhagavata gita say Krishna is supreme God. Vedas say Indra  is supreme God. Upanishad say the God is one without second. But on the other hand you have purna which have some conversation between God's like SHIVA VISHNU AND BRAHAM.

Comment: Hinduism is Riddle like if someone wanted to worship ship he had that path, Somebody wanted to wroship he have path for that also. At the end of the road it depends on which god you worship as supreme... if you worship demigod one will endup in that world.. if one wants moksha.. than one had to worship vishnu only, this knowledge is got when one studies, Veds, Upanishad,  purana, ithihasa.

Comment: Shiva, Vishnu, Durga etc., are Puranic gods of Kaliyuga, Vedas mention 33 koti gods like Indra, Agni, Vayu, Varuna, Mitra, Rudra etc., but real God is one called Brahman or Atman which is omnipresent consciousness. https://wordandsilence.com/2016/09/21/uma-instructs-the-gods-kena-upanishad/ "They call him Indra, Mitra, Varuna, Agni, and he is heavenly nobly-winged Garutman. To what is One, sages give many a title."Rig Veda 1.164.46